# Views inside rows of TableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am a new to iphone Application Development so maybe this might be an easy question. I have a table View whose contents are decided dynamically depending on some conditions. I have created a few views in the storyboard and are being used in other part of the application. Under one of the condition, I want the contents of the table to be those views (as in one view per row) with some one line text on top of the views and in some cases I want to write just some texts. Since the contents are decided dynamically I also have to set the height of the rows dynamically. Is this kind of UITableViewController possible? How do I execute this task. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the **2 methods** that you have to configure for the **UITableView** delegate method in order to achieve that results are:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == x)
    {
        return 44.0;
    } else {
        return 60.0;
    }                       
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if([indexPath row] == x)
    {
       [cellForBigList addSubview:one_view];
    } else {
        [cellForBigList addSubview:another_view];
    }

return cell;
}
```

This is an example in order to **load a view from the storyboard**:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

Comment: but how do I get reference to those views which are in storyboard?

Comment: I added an example in order to load a view from the storyboard. I hope that helps!